# pop unique items from queue and use in multiple threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, queue

I don't understand how to have each thread pop a unique item off the queue and run the function concurrently. The way this is currently written it runs linearly, two threads run by popping the same item from the queue.

How could I have the loop pass unique items from the queue to each thread?

```
import sys
import subprocess
import threading
import Queue

def pinger(host):
    subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c 1', '-W 1', host])

ping_hosts = ['google.com', 'yahoo.com', 'disney.com', 'myspace.com','www.pingler.com', 'www.pingmylink.com',
'www.pingoat.net' ,'www.blogsearch.google.com' ,'pingmyblog.com', 'www.twingly.com', 'www.weblogs.com', 'auto-ping.com' ]

ping_hosts = [ 'google.com', 'yahoo.com', 'disney.com']

def Main():
    q = Queue.Queue()
    for item in ping_hosts:
        q.put(item)

    while q.qsize() != 0:
        host = q.get()
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=pinger, args=(host,)
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=pinger, args=(host,)
        t1.start()
        t2.start()
        t1.join()
        t2.join()

    print "Main Completed"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your worker threads get to ping the same host, because you give the same host value to them. But the main problem with your code is that you consume the queue in the main (single) thread. What you do is put tasks in a queue (main thread), then get them (main thread) and start two worker threads, that do the ping (thread 1, thread 2), then join them (back in main thread again) and do that while there're tasks in a queue.

Also, the `popen` actually starts a new process to do the `ping`, so you might not even need the threads if it's only the ping you're interested in, just:

```
for host in ping_hosts:
    subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c 1', '-W 1', host])
```

But assuming your question is about threading, not doing the ping...
When using a queue, usually, you put tasks (data) in it in one thread, called the "producer", and get and process tasks (data) in another thread, called the "consumer", running simultaneously. Of course there may be several producers and several consumers.

So, in your case what you want is: put the hosts in the queue (main thread), start worker threads, that will get the data from the queue (thread 1, thread 2) and process it (same thread 1, thread 2), running simultaneously.

Try like this:

```
import subprocess
import threading
import Queue


def ping(host):
    """Pings a host."""
    print("Pinging '%s'" % host)
    subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c 1', '-W 1', host])


def pinger_thread(thread_name, task_queue):
    """Gets the data from the queue and processes it."""
    while task_queue.qsize() != 0:
        host = task_queue.get()
        print("%s: pinging '%s'" % (thread_name, host))
        ping(host)


def main():
    ping_hosts = ['google.com', 'yahoo.com', 'disney.com']

    # Fill the queue
    q = Queue.Queue()
    for item in ping_hosts:
        q.put(item)

    # Start the threads, that will consume data from the queue
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=pinger_thread, args=("Thread 1", q))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=pinger_thread, args=("Thread 2", q))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()

    print("Main Completed")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output:

```
python2 test.py 
Thread 1: pinging 'google.com'
Pinging 'google.com'
Thread 2: pinging 'yahoo.com'
Pinging 'yahoo.com'
Thread 1: pinging 'disney.com'
Pinging 'disney.com'
Main Completed
PING google.com (74.125.232.231) 56(84) bytes of data.
PING yahoo.com (206.190.36.45) 56(84) bytes of data.
PING disney.com (199.181.131.249) 56(84) bytes of data.
...
--- google.com ping statistics ---
...
--- disney.com ping statistics ---
...
--- yahoo.com ping statistics ---
...
```

I removed some `ping` command output as irrelevant. But what's important, you can see that the hosts are processed by two threads in order.

Comment: Nikita, thanks so much for a great response.. This really helped me develop a understanding of how threads are supposed to work. Thanks for taking the time to help a noob understand!

Comment: @MikeDevlin, no problem, good luck learning programming and Python! )